# How can I filter a list in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose, I have a list `rx`, and I want to create a new list `xs` which will only contain the even numbers from the list `rx`.

**How can I do that?**

The following code isn't giving the correct answer:

```
rx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

xs = [rx[x%2==0] for x in rx] # <==========

print(xs)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Another question is: what does this type of notation called in Python? Is it lambda expression?

Comment: These aren't lambdas, but Python does have them. See https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Comment: Lambdas in Python are very lacking compared to other languages, and are rarely useful. Python is not a functional language from the developers perspective, although some of the syntax has a definite "functional-like" quality to it-- in particular, list comprehensions (your last question suggests you noticed this), and generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
rx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
xs = [x for x in rx if x % 2 == 0]
# [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give the items having an even index position:

```
xs = [rx[n] for n in range(1, len(rx), 2)]
```

This will give the items that are themselves even:

```
xs = [x for x in rx if x%2==0]
```

In both cases, these are referred to as list comprehensions.

This:

```
[rx[x%2==0] for x in rx]
```

is just oscillating between the first 2 items in the list `rx`, due to the  behavior of `True` and `False` in python:

```
>>> rx[True]
2
>>> rx[False]
1
```